# How to stop Spark from loading defaults?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I do a spark-submit, the defaults conf set up in the SPARK_HOME directory is found and loaded into the System properties.

I want to stop the defaults conf from being loaded, and just get the command line arguments, so that I may re-order how spark is configured before creating my spark context.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can modify `spark-env.sh` and `spark-defaults.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I found acceptable for my issue:

Create a blank "blank.conf" file, and supply it to spark using --properties

```
${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --master local --properties-file "blank.conf" # etc
```

Spark will use the conf in its configuration instead of finding the defaults conf. You can then manually load up the defaults conf later, before creating your SparkContext, if that's your desire.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to modify configurations.

1. According to the spark docs, you can modify configs at runtime with flags (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html):

> The Spark shell and spark-submit tool support two ways to load
>   configurations dynamically. The first are command line options, such
>   as --master, as shown above. spark-submit can accept any Spark
>   property using the --conf flag... **Any values specified as flags or in the properties file will be passed on to the application and merged with those specified through SparkConf.**

which means you can kick off your jobs like this:

```
./bin/spark-submit --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" myApp.jar
```

2. OR, you can go edit the `spark-defaults.conf` and not have to pass additional flags in your spark-submit command.

Comment: Thanks. These won't for me unfortunately. I want to allow our program to configure spark by those properties, or a properties file, or the defaults conf (in that order). I want to handle the properties file after the spark-submit (in my main). Finally, wiping out the defaults won't work either because that is the default for our busy cluster. A spark-shell should continue to use those settings.. I am more certain this is not a possibility without some hacking or modifying the source.

Comment: "I want to handle the properties file after the spark-submit" -- are you saying you want to change spark config properties mid-job?

Comment: From my tests, it seems like you can configure a SparkConf however you want. Once you create your SparkContext with the SparkConf, that's it, it's set in stone.

Comment: sure... you _can_ do what you want, but you have to worry about _when_ -- once a context is instantiated, that context will stay that way until you kill it and instantiate a new context, AFAIK

Comment: It seems like there are some properties which cannot be overridden. For example, see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/metrics/MetricsConfig.scala#L54C5-L54C25 which hard-codes some default properties. And it doesn't seem possible to get rid of them by setting them to a blank string or to `null`, for example it throws "java.lang.NullPointerException: null value for spark.metrics.conf.*.sink.servlet.class".